# Shortcut link to send multiple commands in 1 link

Tags: html, hyperlink, css-selectors, command, imacros

How to turn below into a complete link ?

below are from imacro

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:index.php ATTR=NAME:combatSetId CONTENT=%355181
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:index.php ATTR=NAME:submit

Comment: I'm not looking for help on imacro... i just provided the commands or buttons recorded by imacro... so i'm looking to get URL doing these actions , for example  https://www.xxxx.com/index.php?cmd=clan&subcmd=groups&subcmd2=create

Comment: Oh...!, perfect for the Follow-up... (Sorry, but that's "rare" on this Forum, ah-ah...!) - But hum..., you'll need to use some Syntax/Protocol which is iMacros specific for your Browser to "understand" that your "Link" is supposed to run some iMacros Script...

Comment: a friend told me use chrome dev tool> network traffic inspector to get the link but its not working or maybe i dont know how to get it from that method

Comment: Hum, OK... I still don't really understand what Functionality exactly you want..., the Link you posted in your previous Comment has nothing specific/related to iMacros indeed...